# It is send a notification when a entity is created?

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I want to know if it is send a notification when an entity is created. For example: if I have Orion connected with cygnus using the notification channel, when an entity is created cygnus will note this change?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the subscription. If you have an ONCHANGE subscription in Orion and the subscription "covers" the created entity, then a notification is sent to the receiver, i.e. the endpoint specified in the reference field in the subscription (either Cygnus or other).